# is it correct to use (each activity he engaged to)

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correctly used ?

> They wish him to be the best in each activity he engaged to ...

To be engaged in an activity/to be engaged to a person

engage in something :

to take part in something; to make someone take part in something

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please [edit] your question instead of adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is incorrect:

- They wish him to be the best in each activity he engaged to...

One cannot be **engaged to an activity**! The correct expression is "[**engage in something**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/engage-in)" - *to take part in a particular activity, especially one that involves competing with other people or talking to them*. There might also be a confusion in using tenses and the word "**each**" here.

- They wish him (**now**) to be the best in each (**whichever/whatever/every**) he engaged in (**in the past**)...

You can try to configure an option, depending on the context you imply:

- They wish him to be the best in **whichever/whatever/every activity** he **engages in/participate in/joins/takes part in/becomes involved in**...